# Getting Internal server error in file uploading?

Tags: linux, playframework, ubuntu-14.04, multipartform-data, tomcat8

I am new to linux environment.I have a web application which is running fine in windows environment and it is developed using play framework.Now we want to move our application from windows to linux. Here issue is,while uploading files i'm getting internal server error.I have given permissions as 777 for folder.Even the controller doesn't invoke the method,how to solve it?I am unable to find where the error goes,For all help thanks in advance.

Error is :[image]
       Controller action :

```
   @helper.form(action =routes.HoForms.uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice(),'enctype -> "multipart/form-data" ,'id -> "shiftSummaryForm")
  {
  }
```

In routes file :

```
 POST   /HeadOfficeForms/upload                 controllers.HoForms.uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice()
```

Controller method :

```
public static Result uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice() throws Exception {
    Logger.info("@C HoForms -->> uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice() -->> ");
 }
```

Upload method() :

```
public static Result uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice() throws Exception {

    final String basePath = "/var/www/html/pdfs/";

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String startDate = format.format(date);
    date = format.parse(startDate);

    play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body()
            .asMultipartFormData(); 

    String formType = body.asFormUrlEncoded().get("formType")[0];

    FilePart upFile = body.getFile("hoFormFiles");
    String fileName = upFile.getFilename();
    try {

        File ftemp = new File(basePath + "HeadOfficeForms/" + formType
                + "");
        ftemp.mkdirs();

        String filePathString = "HeadOfficeForms/" + formType + "/"
                + fileName;
        File f1 = new File(ftemp.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);
        File file = upFile.getFile();
        file.setWritable(true);
        file.setReadable(true);
        f1.setWritable(true);
        f1.setReadable(true);
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), f1.toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING);
        HoForm.create(fileName, date, formType, filePathString);
        flash("success", fileName + "  Has been Successfully Uploaded");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return redirect(routes.HoForms.showHoFormUploadPage());
}
```

Comment: Please respond anyone.

Comment: I have shared my upload method.In which where i have to change the code?

Comment: You could try to give the permissions recursive like chmod  -R 777 /path